# Open a series of terminal and run bash files

Tags: python, bash, terminal, submit, tmux

I have a lot of bash files which need to be executed in separated terminals. It is noted that it took 1 hour to run a bash file with 2 cores. I would like to write a python code that will open a series of terminals at a time and submit bash files automatically. I thought about FOR loop and Sub-process library but I cannot get what I want.

Could you please help me with this?

Thank you in advanced!

P/s: I am using Ubuntu 16.04, Python 2.7.

Comment: Do you simply need to run the jobs in parallel, or do you really need an actual terminal for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use screen/tmux for such kind of things. Example for a tmux:

```
tmux new-session 'script1 param1' \; split-window 'script2 param2'
```

Tmux will open two terminal in splitted window, and run your scripts in same time. If you need run more scripts, just add another `\; split-window 'script param'`.

If you need run it from bootup scripts or from cron, you can run it detached:

```
tmux new-session -s my-session 'script1 param1' \; split-window 'script2 param2' \; detach-client
```

If you like to see what happend in detached tmux, you can attach to it again:

```
tmux att -t my-session
```

Also you can put all commands to separated config file and run it. For example create file tmux-run-my-scripts.conf

```
new-session -s my-session 'script1 param1'
split-window 'script2 param2'
detach-client
```

And run it:

```
tmux source-file /path/to/tmux-run-my-scripts.conf
```

Comment: What a great solution! Thank you!